# Android Studio Debug NDK/JNI Mapbox Library

Tags: android, c++, debugging, android-studio, android-ndk

I would like to use the Android Mapbox GL library for a project. I will need to modify the source, so I am attempting to include the mapbox-gl-native project source as a git submodule. I'm new to this, so if I'm on the wrong track using a git submodule, let me know that too.

Here's the project:

https://github.com/bessermt/TriMetRail

It all seems to work, but I can't get the debugger to step into the C++ source of the library with Android Studio. I suspect that since the project is only showing me the Java source files and not the C++, that is a clue to what I'm missing.

If anyone has an idea on how to do this, it would be much appreciated.

thx.

Answer (score 0):

The library you reference [uses](https://github.com/bessermt/mapbox-gl-native/blob/master/platform/android/build.gradle#L9) the *old* gradle plugin:

> ```
> classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'
> ```

The *experimental* plugin is required today to debug native code in Android Studio. Updating all build scripts, with all the dependencies, for the new plugin may be a tricky task, so I would suggest that you post your request [on GitHub](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-native/issues).

I doubt this will make it into the [android-v3.1.0 milestone](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-native/milestones/android-v3.1.0).

Answer (score 0):

I think use the experiment version of the gradle may fix the problem